# How to append a new div element that is sibling of first div created using d3?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

Basically, I want to append a new div after other div: **not a children div, but a sibling of the first div created**.

Using the next `Code`, I'm getting a div inside a h4 :(

```
let content = d3.select('#id_')
let divs = content.selectAll('div')
    .data(data.keys) // It contains 8 objects, will return 8 divs.
    .enter()
    .append('div')
    .attr('class', 'mydiv')
    .append('h4')
    .text((d) => {
      return d.title
    })
    .append('div')
    .attr('class', 'new-div')
```

I got the number of divs I need. However, new div element with class `new-div` is inside `h4` tag.

I want to create something in this order:

```
<!-- Divs created with d3 -->
<div class='mydiv'>
  <h4>Title</h4>
</div>
<div class='new-div'></div>
```

I also tried using `.insert` after appending `h4` tag:

```
    ...
    .append('h4')
    .text((d) => {
      return d.title
    })
    .insert('div')
    .attr('class', 'new-div')
```

But result is the same.

I know hierarchy in this process is not only important, but it builds tags according to each step. Is there a way to create a new div element that is sibling of first div created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to let you know, the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47622400/5768908) (at the time of writing) creates this structure:

```
<div class='mydiv'>
    <h4>Title</h4>
</div>
<div class='mydiv'>
    <h4>Title</h4>
</div>
<div class='new-div'></div>
<div class='new-div'></div>
```

As you can see, all the divs with the class `"new-div"` will come after the `.mydiv` divs. I have a strong feeling that this is not what you want.

If you want to create them one after the other, you have different options, like this (cumbersome) `each()`:

```js
var content = d3.select("body");
var data = [{
  title: "foo"
}, {
  title: "bar"
}];
var divs = content.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter();

divs.each(function(d) {
  content.append("div")
    .attr('class', 'mydiv')
    .append('h4')
    .text(() => {
      return d.title
    });
  content.append('div')
    .attr("class", "new-div");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

This will create the following structure:

```
<div class='mydiv'>
    <h4>Title</h4>
</div>
<div class='new-div'></div>
<div class='mydiv'>
    <h4>Title</h4>
</div>
<div class='new-div'></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.select(function() { return this.parentElement.parentElement; })` before append the second `div`. In this case you don't break the chaining and your selection returns parent element so the second appended `div` will be sibling for the first appended `div`. Check the demo below:

```js
var data = [{ title: 'foo', country: 1 }, { title: 'bar', country: 2 } ];

let divs = d3.select('body')
    .selectAll('div')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('div')
    .attr('class', 'mydiv')
    .append('h4')
    .text((d) => {
      return d.title
    })
    .select(function() { return this.parentElement.parentElement; })
    .append('div')
    .data(data)
    .attr('class', function(d) { return 'country-' + d.country; })
    .text(function(d) {return d.country });
```

```css
.mydiv {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-color: pink;
  display: inline-block;
}

.country-1, .country-2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-color: aqua;
  display: inline-block;
}

h4 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.12.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, @mikhail. all divs created after `div` like `mydiv` class example, will be children? or is there way to create new div below `mydiv` class?

Comment: Now it works. But is adding just the last value in data to each `new-div`. I will figure out.

Comment: @RamiroTormenta "But is adding just the last value" - What do you mean?

Comment: To this new-div I am inserting also a `class` and `id` comming from data that was entered. All siblings has the same value, comming from last object in data. For example: `<div class='country-15'></div><div class='country-15'></div><div class='country-15'></div><div class='country-15'>...`

Comment: @RamiroTormenta Oh, ok. I updated the answer, check, please. You should use `.data(data)` method again for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
let divs = content.selectAll('div')
    .data(data.keys) // It contains 8 objects, will return 8 divs.
    .enter()
    .append('div')
    .attr('class', 'mydiv'); // stop here

// title
divs.append('h4')
  .text((d) => {
    return d.title
  });

// child div
let childDivs = divs.append('div')
  .attr('class', 'mychilddiv');

// second child div
let childDivs2 = childDivs.append('div')
  .attr('class', 'mychilddiv2');

// third child div
let childDivs3 = childDivs2.append('div')
  .attr('class', 'mychilddiv3');

// add h4 to second child
childDivs2.append('h4')
.text('second child')
```

You can chain as you want like this..

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question, I think I do not explained well. With this example now new div element is out of `h4` tag, but is inside children of first div. I am trying to create this new div been sibling of first div created. Thanks, @pirs